# Removing SKSpiteNode from parent

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im trying to remove SKSpriteNodes from the parent, "self".
I create the nodes via a for loop inside a function I call every time I need to update the number of nodes. This nodes represent the number of lives a player has inside the game.

```
func starsSpwan() {
    self.starNode.removeFromParent()
    var spaceInX:CGFloat = 0
    for var i = 0; i<gameLife; i=i+1 {

        starsTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "star")
        starsTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
        starNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: starsTexture)
        starNode.zPosition = 30
        starNode.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        starNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 30 + spaceInX, y: CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + 30)
        self.addChild(starNode)
        println(starNode)
        spaceInX = spaceInX + 40
    }

}
```

Basically the variable gameLife decides how many stars to add. I add the             self.starNode.removeFromParent()
 at the beginning because if the player looses a life I want to delete all 3 stars first and then add again only 2 stars and so on.

My problem is that currently this works only the first time the user looses a life. the nodes get deleted and 2 stars are added again. But if the player looses again another life the nodes don't get deleted and an extra node is added. Still this in unnoticeable because the node is added on top of an existing node.

New code still not working correctly

```
func starsSpwan() {

    self.nodeStar.removeFromParent()
    var spaceInX:CGFloat = 0

    for var i = 0; i<gameLife; i=i+1 {

        starsTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "star")
        starsTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
        starNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: starsTexture)
        starNode.zPosition = 30
        starNode.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
        starNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 30 + spaceInX, y: CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + 30)
        starNode.name = "stars"
        self.addChild(starNode)
        println(starNode)
        spaceInX = spaceInX + 40
        nodeStar = self.childNodeWithName("stars")!

    }

}
```

Comment: isn't it obvious? You have a single variable starNode that holds a reference to a single sprite, so you can only ever remove one sprite (the one created last). You'll need an array or tag your sprites and later enumerate them with the node search functionality.

Comment: How can I remove all of the sprites?

Comment: You can assign a name to the sprites with starNode.name = "starNode" and then remove the sprites with let node = self.childNodeWithName("starNode") and node?.removeFromParent()

Comment: I tried but still have problems, sometimes I can delete all stars or add stars with no problem but others stars are not deleted even though the gameLife has been reduced. I added my no code to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

```
func starsSpawn() {
    // Remove all sprites named "stars"
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("stars") {
        node, stop in
        node.removeFromParent();
    }
    var spaceInX:CGFloat = 0

    for var i = 0; i<gameLife; i=i+1 {

        starsTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "star")
        starsTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
        starNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: starsTexture)
        starNode.zPosition = 30
        starNode.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
        starNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 30 + spaceInX, y: CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + 30)
        starNode.name = "stars"
        self.addChild(starNode)
        println(starNode)
        spaceInX = spaceInX + 40
    }
}
```