# How to get all child nodes with name in Swift with Scene Kit

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am trying to develop a basic game and I have a scene with several child nodes added to the root node. Each node has one of two names, either `friend` or `enemy`.

If a user touches one of the `enemy` nodes I want to remove *all* child nodes that are named `enemy`.

I have tried several things, but can't seem to get anything working.

In my `touchesBegan` function:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   let touch = touches.first!
   let location = touch.location(in: gameView)
   let hitList = gameView.hitTest(location, options: nil)

   if let hitObject = hitList.first {
      let node = hitObject.node

      //This doesn't work
      gameScene.rootNode.childNodes(passingTest: { (node, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool in 
      node.removeFromParentNode()
   } 
}
```

I have also tried to use `gameScene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes(withName:)` but I can't get that working either.

What I *can* get working is if I do something like this in there instead:

```
if node.name == "enemy" {
    node.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

However this will only remove the single node that was hit, not all of them. How can I get all of the child nodes with a certain name in Swift with Scene Kit?

Comment: enumerateChildNodes(withName: "enemy", using: { node, _ in

})

Comment: @ElTomato This gives me an error `Extra argument 'using' in call`

Comment: `enumerateChildNodes(withName:)` should work, here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748966/1187415

Comment: @MartinR I believe OP is working with SceneKit (`SCNNode` instances) and not SpriteKit; there's usually overlap between the two, but it seems as if the `enumerateChildNodes(withName:using:)` method present for `SKNode` is not present for `SCNNode`. `childNodes(passingTest:)` could probably be used for the latter, though, or simply a `filter` call on the `childNodes` property; although I'm unsure if these are equivalent for a multi-child hierarchy (node hierarchy depth > 1).

Comment: @dfri: That explains it, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Filter out the nodes with matching name and remove them from the parent node:

```
gameScene.rootNode.childNodes.filter({ $0.name == "Enemy" }).forEach({ $0.removeFromParentNode() })
```

Comment: @Oskar, Could you please check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543919/arkit-skvideonode-continue-playing-while-node-is-out-of-scene-pause-is-not-wo